# Adding or changing media types to use when serving files with getFromFile

Tags: scala, mime-types, akka-http

I have a route which serves static files which looks like this:

```
get {
  (pathPrefix("appContent" / Segment) & respondWithHeader(Connection("close"))) { appTemplateId =>
    pathSingleSlash {
      getFromFile(s"${config.appStorePath}/${appTemplateId}/index.html")
    } ~
      getFromDirectory(s"${config.appStorePath}/${appTemplateId}")
  }
}
```

And for some type of files I would like to change mime type which is sent in response headers. In akka-http mime types are represented as [*MediaType*](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/model/MediaType.scala) objects. My question is it possible to add / replace entries in this media types map or what would be the simplest way to alter content type resolution process?

In the documentation I've found how to [register custom media types](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/http-model.html#registering-custom-media-types) but looks like it is only related to parsing http messages and not to http responses.

Comment: what does `getFromFile` return? when you complete the response, you should set the `Content-Type` header, like : `complete(StatusCodes.Created, List(\`Content-Type\`(\`text/plain(UTF-8)\`)), "bar")`.  Check out : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/route-directives/complete.html

Comment: @James it returns `Route`. anyway I solved with content type resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by implementing a custom content type resolver which is used both by `getFromFile()` and `getFromDirectory()`:

```
    implicit val contentTypeResolver = new ContentTypeResolver {
      override def apply(fileName: String) = {
        fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) match {
          case ext @ ("ttf" | "eot" | "otf" | "woff" | "woff2") =>
            ContentType(MediaType.custom(s"font/$ext", binary = true, NotCompressible, List(ext)), () => HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`)
          case _ => ContentTypeResolver.Default.apply(fileName)
        }
      }
    }
```

So basically it checks the file extension and if it's the one we want to set mime type for returns proper content type. Otherwise default content type resolver is used.